# Is polyphase decomposition a way to decompose the signal in time domain?

Tags: filters

My main confusion comes from the fact that polyphase decomposition and filterbanks and usually discussed one after the other. How are they related? Specifically, is polyphase a separation in the time domain of a signal(divide signal into subsequences) and filterbanks can achieve separation in frequency (divide signal into high and low pass components). Is there any other close relationship between the two concepts I might be missing?

Answer (score 1):

> How are they related?

There's an elegant method of implementing certain kinds of filterbanks based on polyphase decomposition of the signal and the filter impulse response.

Plus, the math needed to describe polyphase decomposition of systems in frequency domain is super helpful when understanding equally-spaced filterbanks.

So, I'd say it's a very sensible didactic approach to teach one first, then the other.

> Specifically, is polyphase a separation in the time domain of a signal(divide signal into subsequences) and filterbanks can achieve separation in frequency (divide signal into high and low pass components)

No. There's no duality there; the polyphase decomposition "round-robins" discrete-time samples into components. A filterbank does not do the same for discrete frequencies.